# Is it possible to have a single regular expression that matches against multiple expressions?

Tags: regex

I have a date that I'm allowing to be in multiple formats:

```
24-01-12
january 24 2013
etc
```

is there a way to combine 2 or more distinct regular expressions into one using pipes or another method? I tried nesting brackets but this doesn't work, of course:

```
[regex | regex]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, try this:

```
(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)|([a-z]*)

// So basically:
(regex)|(regex)
```

This matches all words, and the date in the first line.
(use `(?:regex)` if you want non-capturing groups, instead of capturing ones.)

If you were literally placing your regexes in the `[]`, then that was the problem.

Comment: You don't need any parentheses around your subregexes: `\d\d-\d\d-\d\d|[a-z]*` is exactly the same as `(?:\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)|(?:[a-z]*)`. What you do sometimes need is a group around the alternation as a whole, if that alternation is surrounded by other parts of the regex, e. g. `^(?:\d\d-\d\d-\d\d|[a-z]*)$`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Imo, it's more readable if they're grouped like that, and it tends to prevent easily overlooked issues. So, you're right, it's not necessary, but I think it can make a regex easier to work on / with.